# Draggable Boxview doesn't update Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

My first problem is that the box view spawns in the top left corner instead of my specified design grid row 10 and grid column 3

The second problem lays with the drag able view, in the first part of the code local drag able view,  It calls the the touching event properly, but maybe it doesn't get updated in the GUI?

```
<ContentPage>
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="0,40,0,0" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="White" ColumnSpacing="10" RowSpacing="10">
        <Label Text="Red" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <BoxView Color="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
        <BoxView Color="Gray" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
        <Label Text="9" Font ="60" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
        <Label Text="8" Font ="60" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
        <Label Text="7" Font ="60" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
        <Label Text="6" Font ="60" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
        <Label Text="5" Font ="60" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
        <Label Text="4" Font ="60" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
        <Label Text="3" Font ="60" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
        <Label Text="2" Font ="60" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
        <Label Text="1" Font ="60" Grid.Row="9" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
        <Label Text="0" Font ="60" Grid.Row="10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />

  <local:DraggableView x:Name="dragView" DragMode="LongPress" DragDirection="All" >
                <local:DraggableView.Content>
                    <BoxView x:Name="image" BackgroundColor="Pink" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="3"/>
                </local:DraggableView.Content>
        </local:DraggableView>
    </Grid>
```

Helpers

```
public enum DragDirectionType
{
    All,
    Vertical,
    Horizontal
}
public enum DragMode
{
    Touch,
    LongPress
}
```

DraggableView

```
 public partial class DraggableView : ContentView
    {
        public event EventHandler DragStart = delegate { };
        public event EventHandler DragEnd = delegate { };

        public static readonly BindableProperty DragDirectionProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "DragDirection",
            returnType: typeof(DragDirectionType),
            declaringType: typeof(DraggableView),
            defaultValue: DragDirectionType.All,
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public DragDirectionType DragDirection
        {
            get { return (DragDirectionType)GetValue(DragDirectionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DragDirectionProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty DragModeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
           propertyName: "DragMode",
           returnType: typeof(DragMode),
           declaringType: typeof(DraggableView),
           defaultValue: DragMode.LongPress,
           defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public DragMode DragMode
        {
            get { return (DragMode)GetValue(DragModeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DragModeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty IsDraggingProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
          propertyName: "IsDragging",
          returnType: typeof(bool),
          declaringType: typeof(DraggableView),
          defaultValue: false,
          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public bool IsDragging
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsDraggingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsDraggingProperty, value); }
        }


        public void DragStarted()
        {
            DragStart(this, default(EventArgs));
            IsDragging = true;
        }

        public void DragEnded()
        {
            IsDragging = false;
            DragEnd(this, default(EventArgs));
        }

    }
}
```

This is the android part of the code

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(DraggableView), typeof(DraggableViewRenderer))]

namespace BabakusXamarin.Droid
{
    public class DraggableViewRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.View>
    {
        float originalX;
        float originalY;
        float dX;
        float dY;
        bool firstTime = true;
        bool touchedDown = false;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);


            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                LongClick -= HandleLongClick;
            }
        }

        private void HandleLongClick(object sender, LongClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
            if (firstTime)
            {
                originalX = GetX();
                originalY = GetY();
                firstTime = false;
            }
            dragView.DragStarted();
            touchedDown = true;
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        }
        protected override void OnVisibilityChanged(AView.View changedView, [GeneratedEnum] ViewStates visibility)
        {
            base.OnVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);
            if (visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
            {



            }
        }
        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            float x = e.RawX;
            float y = e.RawY;
            var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    if (dragView.DragMode == DragMode.Touch)
                    {
                        if (!touchedDown)
                        {
                            if (firstTime)
                            {
                                originalX = GetX();
                                originalY = GetY();
                                firstTime = false;
                            }
                            dragView.DragStarted();
                        }

                        touchedDown = true;
                    }
                    dX = x - this.GetX();
                    dY = y - this.GetY();
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    if (touchedDown)
                    {
                        if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Horizontal)
                        {
                            SetX(x - dX);
                        }

                        if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Vertical)
                        {
                            SetY(y - dY);
                        }

                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                    touchedDown = false;
                    dragView.DragEnded();
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                    touchedDown = false;
                    break;
            }
            return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
        }

        public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {

            BringToFront();
            return true;
        }

    }


}
```

iOS Part of the code

```
public class DraggableViewRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<View>
    {
        bool longPress = false;
        bool firstTime = true;
        double lastTimeStamp = 0f;
        UIPanGestureRecognizer panGesture;
        CGPoint lastLocation;
        CGPoint originalPosition;
        UIGestureRecognizer.Token panGestureToken;
        void DetectPan()
        {
            var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
            if (longPress || dragView.DragMode == DragMode.Touch)
            {
                if (panGesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
                {
                    dragView.DragStarted();
                    if (firstTime)
                    {
                        originalPosition = Center;
                        firstTime = false;
                    }
                }

                CGPoint translation = panGesture.TranslationInView(Superview);
                var currentCenterX = Center.X;
                var currentCenterY = Center.Y;
                if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Horizontal)
                {
                    currentCenterX = lastLocation.X + translation.X;
                }

                if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Vertical)
                {
                    currentCenterY = lastLocation.Y + translation.Y;
                }

                Center = new CGPoint(currentCenterX, currentCenterY);

                if (panGesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)
                {
                    dragView.DragEnded();
                    longPress = false;
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                RemoveGestureRecognizer(panGesture);
                panGesture.RemoveTarget(panGestureToken);
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
                panGesture = new UIPanGestureRecognizer();
                panGestureToken = panGesture.AddTarget(DetectPan);
                AddGestureRecognizer(panGesture);


                dragView.RestorePositionCommand = new Command(() =>
                {
                    if (!firstTime)
                    {

                        Center = originalPosition;
                    }
                });

            }

        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        }

        public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {
            base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
            lastTimeStamp = evt.Timestamp;
            Superview.BringSubviewToFront(this);
            lastLocation = Center;
        }
        public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {
            if (evt.Timestamp - lastTimeStamp >= 0.5)
            {
                longPress = true;
            }
            base.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: For starters `Grid.Row="10"` is actually the 11th Row and `Grid.Column="3"` is the 4th column, it starts at 0 like you would expect the beginning of an array to, but you currently only have 10 rows and 3 columns. As for your `DraggableViewRenderer` I would suggest changing the  `Element.TranslationX` and `Element.TranslationY` instead of the native views positions.

Comment: Alright, so how do I change where the boxview spawn? Changed it t row 9 and column 2 but it still spawn on the topleft. Secondly, what did you mean with element.translationx isntead of the native view positions?

Comment: Your `Gird.Row` and `Grid.Column` should be on the `<local:DraggableView/>` not the BoxView and for example you're doing `SetX(x - dX);` on the android render native view try changing that to the Forms view `Element.TranslationX`

Comment: Alright, still unsure what you mean with the element.translationX should I just instead of SetX write Element.TranslationX; or?

Comment: I posted an implementation I created in the past if you are still having problems with your implementation to give you a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first problem is that the box view spawns in the top left corner instead of my specified design grid row 10 and grid column 3

As Nick mentioned above, `Grid.Row` ,`Grid.Column` starts at 0 ,and you should set them on the `DraggableView` instead of `BoxView` .

Modify your code as below

```
<local:DraggableView x:Name="dragView" DragMode="LongPress" DragDirection="All" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="2" >
      <local:DraggableView.Content>
            <BoxView x:Name="image" BackgroundColor="Pink" />
      </local:DraggableView.Content>
</local:DraggableView>
```

> The second problem lays with the drag able view, in the first part of the code local drag able view, It calls the the touching event properly, but maybe it doesn't get updated in the GUI?

Which platform did you test on ? Android or iOS?

It works perfectly on my side(iOS simulator).

[image]

#### Update:

After changed the logic of method `OnTouchEvent` , it works as expected.

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        float x = e.RawX;
        float y = e.RawY;
        var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                if (dragView.DragMode == DragMode.Touch)
                {
                    if (!touchedDown)
                    {
                        if (firstTime)
                        {
                            originalX = GetX();
                            originalY = GetY();
                            firstTime = false;
                        }
                        dragView.DragStarted();
                    }

                    touchedDown = true;
                }
                dX = x - this.GetX();
                dY = y - this.GetY();
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                //if (touchedDown)
                //{
                    if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Horizontal)
                    {
                        SetX(x - dX);
                    }

                    if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Vertical)
                    {
                        SetY(y - dY);
                    }

                //}
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                touchedDown = false;
                dragView.DragEnded();
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                touchedDown = false;
                break;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Used the Android part to test, so glad to hear that the iOS works. Hadn't tested that one yet

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work with the Android part :/

Comment: @J.Dhaik It is my fault, see my update, this method should always return `true` rather than `base.OnTouchEvent(e)`

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I have made a similar control. Part of the problem I had on Android was I also had to incorporate the screen density for it to drag properly. Here is my implementation.

Control:

```
public class DraggableContentView : ContentView
{
    public event EventHandler TouchEnded;
    public event EventHandler TouchesBegan;
    public event EventHandler PositionChanged;

    public void InvokeTouchBegan()
    {
        var parentLayout = Parent as Layout<View>;
        parentLayout?.RaiseChild(this);
        TouchesBegan?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void InvokePositionChanged()
    {
        PositionChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void InvokeTouchEnded()
    {
        TouchEnded?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Android Renderer:

```
public class DraggableContentViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<DraggableContentView, Android.Views.View>
{
    private float _density, _downX, _downY;

    public DraggableContentViewRenderer()
    {
        _density = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DraggableContentView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Element != null)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                SetNativeControl(new Android.Views.View(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context));
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (!Element.IsEnabled)
            return false;

        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                {
                    _downX = e.GetX();
                    _downY = e.GetY();
                    Element.InvokeTouchBegan();
                    break;
                }
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                {
                    var x = e.GetX();
                    var y = e.GetY();
                    var dx = (x - _downX) / _density;
                    var dy = (y - _downY) / _density;
                    Element.TranslationX += dx;
                    Element.TranslationY += dy;
                    Element.InvokePositionChanged();
                    break;
                }
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
            case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                {
                    Element.InvokeTouchEnded();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

iOS Renderer:

```
public class DraggableContentViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<DraggableContentView, UIView>
{
    private CGPoint _offsetLocation;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DraggableContentView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Element != null)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                SetNativeControl(new UIView());
            }
        }
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);

        var t = touches.ToArray<UITouch>();
        if (t.Length != 1) 
            return;

        var loc = t[0].LocationInView(this);

        var touchedView = HitTest(loc, evt);
        if (touchedView == null) 
            return;

        _offsetLocation = new CGPoint(loc.X - touchedView.Frame.X, loc.Y - touchedView.Frame.Y);

        Element.InvokeTouchBegan();
    }

    public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);

        var newLoc = ((UITouch)touches.First()).LocationInView(this);
        Element.TranslationX += newLoc.X - _offsetLocation.X;
        Element.TranslationY += newLoc.Y - _offsetLocation.Y;
        Element.InvokePositionChanged();
    }

    public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);

        Element.InvokeTouchEnded();
    }
}
```