# Draggable Images Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a user interface where a user can drag an image around the screen atop a background image. Currently the `DraggableImage` is being moved around with some sliders that change `DraggableBounds` in the view model.

`<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Image Source="{Binding DraggableImage, Mode=TwoWay}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{Binding DraggableBounds}" />
    <Image Source="{Binding FrameImage, Mode=TwoWay}" Aspect="AspectFit" WidthRequest="1300" HeightRequest="500"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>`

I've tried using the Pan Gesture that's on Microsofts Xamarin docs with little success. I'm not trying to pan within an image but move a smaller image over a larger. Is there an existing pattern to solve this?

Comment: You'll probably have to create a custom renderer for each platform or find one that has been already implemented to make a draggable control. I made a similar [control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47389182/draggable-boxview-doesnt-update-xamarin/47422852#47422852) that inherits from `ContentView` that can contain any contents that you want to be able to drag.

Comment: @Nick thanks, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Keep in mind with Xamarin.Forms 2.5+ Android renderers should pass the Context in with the constructor, which that example is from before that change.